# Adding Chart title and Axis titles to Grouped Charts

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm having an issue trying to create a macro to put Chart titles and axis titles on to my graphs, I've looked online and have tried suggestions using both ActiveChart.SetElement and ActiveChart.HasTitle = True but I can't get either to work. I suspect that my issue lies in the fact that multiple graphs are being created at one time. The code I'm using is below:

```
Sub Plotting()

Dim LR As Long

LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim aSheet As Worksheet
For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'Strain vs Time
With aSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    .SetSourceData Source:=aSheet.Range(" '" & aSheet.Name & "'!B3:B15000,'" 
& aSheet.Name & "'!G3:G15000")
End With
Next

For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'Stress vs Time
    With aSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    .SetSourceData Source:=aSheet.Range(" '" & aSheet.Name & "'!B3:B15000,'" 
& aSheet.Name & "'!H3:H15000")
End With
Next

For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'Stress vs Strain
With aSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    .SetSourceData Source:=aSheet.Range(" '" & aSheet.Name & "'!G3:G15000,'" 
& aSheet.Name & "'!H3:H15000")
End With
Next

End Sub
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Domenic Solved the Initial problem and now I have working code. Now I'm attempting to reorient the Y-axis title to be adjacent to the axis. I've tried this :

```
For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'Strain vs Time
    With aSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        .SetSourceData Source:=aSheet.Range("'" & aSheet.Name & 
"'!B3:B15000,'" & aSheet.Name & "'!G3:G15000")
    .SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart 
    .SetElement msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleBelowAxis 
    .SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis
    .ChartTitle.Text = "MyChartTitle" 'change the chart title as desired
    .Axes(Type:=xlCategory, AxisGroup:=xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = 
"MyCategoryAxisTitle" 'change the category axis title as desired
    .Axes(Type:=xlValue, AxisGroup:=xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = 
"MyValueAxisTitle" 'change the value axis title as desired
End With
Next
```

When I run the code I get 'Run-time error '424': Object required and the line where the Y axis is named becomes highlighted. Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
 For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'Strain vs Time
    With aSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        .SetSourceData Source:=aSheet.Range("'" & aSheet.Name & 
"'!B3:B15000,'" & aSheet.Name & "'!G3:G15000")
    .SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart 
    .SetElement msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleBelowAxis 
    .SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleHorizontal
    .ChartTitle.Text = "MyChartTitle" 'change the chart title as desired
    .Axes(Type:=xlCategory, AxisGroup:=xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = 
"MyCategoryAxisTitle" 'change the category axis title as desired
    .Axes(Type:=xlValue, AxisGroup:=xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = 
"MyValueAxisTitle" 'change the value axis title as desired
End With
Next
```

This works but the Axis Title becomes Horizontal.

This is what I want the output to look like ideally.

[Sample Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFAC1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first one...

```
For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'Strain vs Time
    With aSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        .SetSourceData Source:=aSheet.Range("'" & aSheet.Name & "'!B3:B15000,'" & aSheet.Name & "'!G3:G15000")
        .SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart 'change the position as desired
        .SetElement msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleBelowAxis 'change the position as desired
        .SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleVertical 'change the position as desired
        .ChartTitle.Text = "MyChartTitle" 'change the chart title as desired
        .Axes(Type:=xlCategory, AxisGroup:=xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "MyCategoryAxisTitle" 'change the category axis title as desired
        .Axes(Type:=xlValue, AxisGroup:=xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "MyValueAxisTitle" 'change the value axis title as desired
    End With
Next
```

The same thing would apply for your other ones.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked great! Do SetElements have to be defined before they can be named?  I tried an approach similar to this earlier but for some reason, it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you need to set the elements first so that their corresponding objects can be made available.

Comment: Any Idea how to make the Y-axis label adjacent to the axis? Ive tried this:

Comment: What have you tried? It should be positioned next to the axis.  Maybe be you don't want the text vertical?  Maybe you want `msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleBelowAxis`?

Comment: I edited the post above to show what I've done and what I'm looking to output.

Comment: Set the value axis title to `msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleBelowAxis`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the code to:

```
Dim LR As Long

LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim aSheet As Worksheet
For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'Strain vs Time
With aSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    .SetSourceData Source:=aSheet.Range("'" & aSheet.Name & "'!B3:B15000,'" & aSheet.Name & "'!G3:G15000")
    .SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart 'change the position as desired
    .SetElement msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleBelowAxis 'change the position as desired
    .SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated 'change the position as desired
    .SetElement msoElementLegendNone
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Strain vs Time" 'change the chart title as desired
    .Axes(Type:=xlCategory, AxisGroup:=xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Time (sec)" 'change the category axis title as desired
    .Axes(Type:=xlValue, AxisGroup:=xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Strain" 'change the value axis title as desired
End With
Next
```

And it solved the problem. Thanks for your help Domenic